# How to implement send data method by using SignalR in Angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Im sharing my code both backend and frontend. I can get values from SignalR easily but I cannot send value by using a function such as invoke, I have tried many things but none of them worked.
Here is my backend part in Asp.NetCore =>
in Startup.cs for global declaration to my lists

```
public static List<TagItemModel> lastValues = new List<TagItemModel>();
public static List<TagItemModel> tempValues = new List<TagItemModel>();
```

in Hub.cs for SignalR Hub Class which is about to listen of the channel

```
public async Task SendValues(string strValueList) {
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveValues", strValueList);
    Startup.tempValues.Clear();
    Startup.tempValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TagItemModel>>(strValueList);
    foreach (var item in Startup.tempValues) {
         var tempValue = Startup.lastValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Name);
         if (tempValue == null) {
             Startup.lastValues.Add(item);
         } else {
                  tempValue.Value = item.Value;
         }
    }
}
```

This is my Front-end part in Angular (by the way, I can get values, there is no problem of it) =>

```
this.anlikDegerler = [
    {Name: 'F1 S1', Value: '25', CustomCode:'A'},
];
...
sendHubConn(message: AnlikSicaklikDegerleri) {
        this.hubConn.invoke<AnlikSicaklikDegerleri>('SendValues', message)
            .then((r) => {
            const resp = JSON.parse(r.toString());
            for(let i=0; i<resp.length; i++){
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerText=`${resp[i].Name}`;
                }
        }).catch(err=> console.log(err));
}
```

I cannot figure it out and also I cannot solve this problem. Friends, if you have any ideas, i will try. I am totally hopeless right now. Lastly, mistake of this code are below of here:
**Error: Failed to invoke 'SendValues' due to an error on the server.**